# Strip out the whitespace without errors

Tags: jquery, minify

My first step of the minify is stripping out whitespaces, but it already gives an error unexpected identifier.

```
<script>
function initializePonzo() {
    bindNavigation();
}

function createDiv(parent) {
    var newItem = $("<div></div>").attr("id", divname).appendTo("#" + parent);
    $(newItem).attr("data-type", typeofcontent);
    $(newItem).addClass(typeofcontent);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are `minify` ing the js file

Comment: From where you get this `divname` and `typeofcontent`??

Comment: Where is `typeofcontent` defined. Please add complete and relevant code

Comment: Please send all the script code, so that we can find a solution,